# IContextMenu all commands are working fine except copy and cut

Tags: winapi, copy, contextmenu, cut, windows-explorer

I am developing a windows-explorer type application, in that I am trying to invoke IContextMenu operations like copy, paste, properties, delete etc, but **only copy and cut** operation is not accomplishing whereas as they are invoking successfully.

Please see below scenario;

I am setting CMINVOKECOMMANDINFO.lpVerb to respective command string ("copy", "paste", "properties" etc).

```
CMINVOKECOMMANDINFO cmici={ sizeof(CMINVOKECOMMANDINFO) };
ZeroMemory( &cmici, sizeof(CMINVOKECOMMANDINFO));
cmici.cbSize = sizeof(CMINVOKECOMMANDINFO);
cmici.fMask=0;
cmici.hwnd=m_pOwnerWnd!=NULL ? m_pOwnerWnd->GetSafeHwnd() : NULL;
cmici.lpVerb= "copy";
cmici.lpParameters= NULL;
cmici.lpDirectory=NULL;
cmici.nShow=SW_SHOWNORMAL;
cmici.dwHotKey=0;
cmici.hIcon=NULL;
```

Fetching ITEMIDLIST's contextmenu;

```
HRESULT hResult = lpParentFolder->GetUIObjectOf(
  m_pOwnerWnd!=NULL ? m_pOwnerWnd->GetSafeHwnd() : NULL, 1,
  (const struct _ITEMIDLIST**)&(lpRelativeIDL), IID_IContextMenu, 0,
  (LPVOID*)&lpcm)
```

Querying contextmenu;

```
hResult=lpcm->QueryContextMenu(hMenu,0,1,0x7fff,dwFlags);
```

Finally invoking;

```
    hResult=lpcm->InvokeCommand(&cmici);

::DestroyMenu(hMenu);

lpcm->Release();

if(FAILED(hResult))  
    return FALSE;

return TRUE;
```

**Command delete, properties, paste etc. are working fine except copy and cut**

Please could any one help me in this regard?

Thanks.

Comment: What actually happens when you invoke the command? How do you know they're not working?

Comment: InvokeCommand(..) returns success (S_OK). 
And regarding working, after clicking **copy** (on any item in my application) I then perform right click on desktop to **paste** it but command **paste** do not appear in contextmenu. Whereas when I repeat same procedure from desktop or from any Windows Explorer window command **paste** gets visible in context menu and it allows me to perform **paste** operation in my application window.

Comment: Use one of the various clipboard utility programs to see what exactly gets put in the clipboard 1) when explorer invokes the copy and 2) when your program invokes the copy.

Comment: @Luke I tried [Ditto](http://ditto-cp.sourceforge.net/) clipboard manager and **1)** it shows file path in clipboard when I perform copy  from windows explorer and **2)** it does not show any entry in clipboard when I perform same operation from my application's window though InvokeCommand(..) return S_OK.

Comment: Issue has been resolved. Thanks _Jonathan Potter_ and _Luke_ for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same issue is mentioned at this [link](http://bcbjournal.org/articles/vol4/0006/Using_the_shell_context_menu.htm) under heading **OleInitialize**.

I moved the call to OleInitialize() to the form’s OnCreate event handler, and **Cut** / **Copy** menu items began working.

Comment: I tried this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22012/Explorer-Shell-Context-Menu in my c# application but the paste operation block the UI. Do you have an idea of a solution?